# A result about LSpace and RLSpace

Tags: computational-complexity, reference-request

I heard that there is a result which is proved that RL\subseteq L^{4/3}, but I don't which paper have proved it.

Can someone tell me this paper?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the currently best known bound is L^{3/2} in
Michael E. Saks, Shiyu Zhou: RSPACE(S) \subseteq DSPACE(S3/2). FOCS 1995 344-353

There was a paper showing Symmetric Log space in L^{4/3}

R. Armoni, A. Ta-Shma, A. Wigderson, S. Zhou.
A (log n )^{4/3} space algorithm for (s,t) connectivity in undirected graphs
Preliminary version in Proceedings of the 29th STOC, pp. 230-239, 1997.
J. ACM, vol. 47, no. 2, 294-311, 2000.

(by now it is known that symmetric log spaces is in log space)

Comment: (And the result that symmetric log spaces is in log space is due to O. Reingold, "Undirected connectivity in log-space", JACM 55(4), 2008.)